# Windows 7 '"Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

On the windows10 version you can install a complete GUI docker tool, in order to configure it. And inside it you can check for "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS". But on windows7 you can't get this gui tool so I'm wondering how to do the same by command line.

[image: What I want to do but with Windows7]

I modified the following on my environment variables :

```
>echo %DOCKER_HOST%
tcp://localhost:2375

>echo %DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY%
0
```

But when I run the command `mvn -Pprod package dockerfile:build` I got the following error :
`HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [...] Conection refused...`

I checked that I've a docker machine running on virtualbox, nothing in localhost.

Any ideas ?

Comment: try `docker.for.win.localhost:2375` that was the only one I got working when I used portainer to connect to a local endpoint and I had a very similar problem to this